# is it my Visual Studio 2008 problem or is it Dreamweaver capability?

Tags: visual-studio, cursor, dreamweaver

Oh no....
I just realized it, that the Visual Studio 2008 is getting me confused.
If we compared to the DreamWeaver later version... not the latest one, okay...
That DreavWeaver has a SPLIT View (in between the design and code).
And here, the Visual Studio 2008 also has that capability.

The difference is that... in Visual Studio 2008,
When the user start Clicking the Designer portion, the cursor on Code view doesn't get into focus. Yeah, meanwhile, in DreamWeaver, at the time user click on the designer portion, the mouse pointer is focusing into the code location accordingly....

Uh, oh.... this is getting me tired. Shall I update something into this Visual Studio 2008 version, guys? :(

Answer (score -1):

use Visual Studio 2010 and be happy

Comment: This is not an answer to the question. You don't even explain that the problem encountered in VS 2008 is *fixed* in VS 2010, not to mention the obvious problem of switching to a new version not being an option...